# Calculating "variance" for a somewhat complicated bet

Tags: vb.net, math, probability, variance, gambling

I have a program that calculates various metrics of a certain kind of bet, such as EV, chance to win, etc. What I also want is a measure of how "variance heavy" the bet is. And what I explicitly mean by this is the following: "after n number of times repeating the bet, what is the probability that you will have run out of X cash." I currently do this by running simulations, but this is very slow. I'm looking for a way to do this with a more direct math/computation solution.

The bet doesn't just have two outcomes. It has one lose state, and any given number of win-states, with different probabilities, and different payouts, data all made available to the program.

This is how I currently do it with simulations:

```
Function GetOutcomeList() As List(Of Integer)
    Dim result As New List(Of Integer)
    For i = 1 To combos
        Dim addcount As Integer = Math.Round((windistribution(i, 0, 1) / winchance(0)) * 500000)
        For j = 1 To addcount
            result.Add(windistribution(i, 0, 0))
        Next
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

The function above populates a list such that any randomly picked element from that list will have the same chance of being picked as its corresponding probability.

```
Function GetVarianceMetric(bankroll As Integer) As Double
    Dim simcount As Integer = 4000
    Dim numofgames As Integer = bankroll / (bet ^ 0.6)
    Dim simspassed As Integer = 0
    Dim outcomeList As List(Of Integer) = GetOutcomeList()
    For sims = 1 To simcount
        Dim cash As Double = bankroll
        For i = 1 To numofgames
            Dim roll As Double = generator.NextDouble
            cash -= bet
            If roll <= winchance(0) AndAlso cash >= 0 Then
                cash += outcomelist(generator.Next(1, outcomelist.Count))
            ElseIf cash <= 0 Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If cash > 0 Then
            simspassed += 1
        End If
    Next
    Return (simspassed / simcount) * 100
End Function
```

The following is my attempt to implement  meowgoesthedog's solution, which ended up being much slower than my monte carlo solution, when tasked with more bets/outcomes:

```
 Structure OutCome
    Dim prob As Double
    Dim cashChange As Integer
End Structure

Function GetNewVarianceMetric(bankroll As Integer) As Double
    Dim n As Integer = 10
    Dim out_list(winstates) As OutCome
    Dim taken(winstates) As Boolean

    For i = 0 To winstates - 1
        Dim biggest() As Integer = {0, 0}
        For j = 1 To winstates
            If taken(j) = False AndAlso (windistribution(j, 0, 0) - betsize) >= biggest(1) Then
                biggest(1) = windistribution(j, 0, 0)
                biggest(0) = j
            End If
        Next
        Dim oc As New OutCome
        oc.cashChange = windistribution(biggest(0), 0, 0) - betsize
        oc.prob = windistribution(biggest(0), 0, 1)
        out_list(i) = oc
        taken(biggest(0)) = True
    Next
    Dim ocLose As New OutCome
    ocLose.cashChange = -betsize
    ocLose.prob = 1 - winchance(0)
    out_list(winstates) = ocLose
    Dim prob_list(winstates) As Double
    Dim c As Double = 0
    For i = winstates To 0 Step -1
        c += out_list(i).prob
        prob_list(i) = c
    Next
    Dim prob_runout As Double = prob_enough(n, bankroll, out_list, prob_list) * 100
    Return prob_runout
End Function

Function prob_enough(n As Integer, x As Integer, out() As OutCome, probs() As Double) As Double
    If x <= 0 Then
        Return 0
    End If
    If n <= 1 Then
        Dim i As Integer = search_smallest(out, x)
        If (i < winstates) Then
            Return probs(i)
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    End If
    Dim S As Double = 0
    For i = winstates To 0 Step -1
        If out(i).cashChange < -x Then
            Exit For
        End If
        S += out(i).prob * prob_enough(n - 1, x + out(i).cashChange, out, probs)
    Next
    Return S
End Function

Function search_smallest(out() As OutCome, x As Integer) As Integer
    Dim left As Integer = 0
    Dim right As Integer = winstates
    While left < right
        Dim i As Integer = (left + right) / 2
        If out(i).cashChange >= -x Then
            right = i
        Else
            left = i + 1
        End If
    End While
    Return left
End Function
```

Comment: Sounds like a simple Monte Carlo simulation to me.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm currently doing. But as I said, it's too slow. For any given bet, it takes almost a second to get a reliable number. If I want to put, say 1000 bet configurations into an array, get this variance metric on each, it would take forever to complete.

Comment: how much do you stake on each bet? X?

Comment: Yeah it needs to handle any bet amount.

Comment: "I'm looking for a way to do this with just pure math" sounds like "I'm looking for a way to do this in a way in which is off-topic on Stack Overflow." Maybe a good idea, but why ask *here*?

Comment: Also -- you could perhaps show how you are currently doing your Monte Carlo. I don't see why it should take "forever" to run 1000 simulations, even if each individual simulation takes e.g. 100,000 steps. Perhaps you can speed up your simulations.

Comment: Maybe "pure math" was the wrong term to use, I never intended to answer to just be pure math. Obviously the implementation of said math would in this scenario at best have to involve some sort of algorithm that represents said math. I will also update my post to involve the monte carlo simulation in a short while.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly, you have a bet that has a number of different ways it can "win" or "lose".  I believe you will first need to determine the appropriate distribution function for each win or loss.  Then, you will need to evaluate each of these functions as an independent variable and determine a distribution function that represents your collection of functions.  In short, you need to find the joint density function of this group of probability functions.  This is not a simple operation, although there are a few ways to go about it.  The exact method you use depends upon the type of distribution function that is represented by each outcome, and the behavior of those functions.

This is not a simple operation, and it is probably easier (but slower) to go about it from an empirical approach as you are doing.

Comment: I'm not the best at math; I don't know where to start with distribution functions or joint density functions. If we construct a very simplified example, could you (or anyone else) try to formulate something that could help me towards the real answer? 
Consider the following: We have a magic die with 10 sides. 1-8 gets you nothing, 9 wins you 30 bucks, 10 wins you 50 bucks. 9 has 15% chance of occurring while 10 has 5%. It costs 5 bucks to play. You have 100 bucks. After 100 games, what is the probability that you will have run out of money and can't continue playing (money is under 5 bucks)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you present does not sound like any measure of "variance" that I know of, so I can only put that on-hold. Also, I will assume that your question is *specifically* about computing the probability of running out of money, instead of about *general* statistical computations (which would be far too broad).

---

For `n` bets and `m` outcomes, there is a deterministic method to solve this problem in [image] time:

1. Say we initially have an array `A` of `m` outcomes, each with associated probability `p` and *change in money* `y` (payout minus initial deposit). Sort this array by `y`.
2. Compute the *cumulative probability* starting from the *end* of the array. Should add up to 1 at the end.
3. Call the routine with `n, X`, where `n` is the number of bets left, and `X` is the current budget.
4. If `n = 1`, using binary search, find the index `i` such that `A[i:] >= -X`. This is the most costly outcome the player can afford. Return the cumulative probability at this index.
5. If `n > 1`, keep a variable `S` for the output probability, and initialize it to 0. Starting from the end for all values of `A[i] >= -X` as above:

   - Perform a recursive call starting from (3), with budget `n - 1, X + A[j].y`.
   - Multiply the return result by `A[j].p` and add to `S`.
   - At the end, return `S`.

---

The above might be very confusing to you. The algorithm explores all possible ways of betting `n` times **without** running out of money, and accumulates their probabilities on the grounds that successive bets are independent.

Note that this is **1 minus** the quantity you want (the probability of running over budget); the reason for computing this quantity is that as along as we are within budget, the amount of money we can spend is always bounded from above, which means we have fewer cases to test.

---

**EDIT:** example implementation:

```
struct outcome
{
   double prob;   // probability "p"
   int change;    // change in money "y"
};

// search for the most expensive bet
static size_t search_smallest(const vector<outcome> & out, int X)
{
   size_t left = 0, right = out.size();
   while (left < right)
   {
      size_t i = (left + right) / 2;
      if (out[i].change >= -X)
         right = i;
      else
         left = i + 1;
   }
   return left;
}

// compute the probability that it is enough
static double prob_enough(unsigned n, int X,
   const vector<outcome> & out, const vector<double> & probs)
{
   if (X <= 0) return 0.0;

   if (n <= 1) {
      size_t i = search_smallest(out, X);
      return (i < out.size()) ? probs[i] : 0.0;
   }

   double S = 0.0;
   for (size_t i = out.size(); i > 0; i--)
   {
      if (out[i - 1].change < -X) break;
      S += out[i - 1].prob * prob_enough(n - 1, X + out[i - 1].change, out, probs);
   }
   return S;
}

int main()
{
   int n, X;
   // input number of bets and budget
   // ...

   vector<outcome> out_list;
   // input different outcomes and fill out_list
   // ...

   // sort out_list with respect to y
   sort(out_list.begin(), out_list.end(),
      [](const outcome & a, const outcome & b) { return a.change < b.change; });

   // create cumulative list
   vector<double> prob_list(out_list.size());
   {
      double c = 0.0;
      for (size_t i = out_list.size(); i > 0; i--)
      {
         c += out_list[i - 1].prob;
         prob_list[i - 1] = c;
      }
   }

   double prob_runout = 1.0 - prob_enough(n, X, out_list, prob_list);
}
```

Test case:

```
X = 7, n = 3

Outcome no.     |  1     2     3
----------------------------------- 
Change      (y) | -10    1     2
Probability (p) | 0.5   0.4   0.1

--> prob_runout = 0.83
```

Confirmation - different ways to run out before all bets have been placed:

```
Outcomes  | Probability
----------|---------------------
[1, ., .] | 0.5         = 0.5
[2, 1, .] | 0.4*0.5     = 0.2
[3, 1, .] | 0.1*0.5     = 0.05
[2, 2, .] | 0.4*0.4*0.5 = 0.08
                  Total = 0.83
```

Comment: This seems extremely helpful for what I'm trying to achieve. Maybe I'm not used to coding solutions being conceptualized in this way, so I'm not sure how to start implementing this. An example in code would be really appreciated. Everything up until 3/4 was straight forward enough, but then it's a bit confusing as to what we're doing, what what X is referring to.

Comment: @user8128940 updated. Apologies I forgot to include - X is the current budget at any point during the call algorithm.

Comment: I'm reading your test case, and we might have a miscommunication in regards to how the bet works. The 3 outcomes you listed, y -10, 1, and 2, are not supposed to pertain to 3 different bets, but are supposed to be 3 different possible outcomes of a single bet. I then want the probability of going broke after running the same bet n number of times. If this is indeed what you have represented here, then I'm sorry for misunderstanding.

Edit: I ran a simulation of your example as I wanted it to work, and it worked out to 83%. I guess how you named the outcomes bet 1, 2, 3 really confused me.

Comment: Apologies as that is indeed what I was trying to represent. Should change `bet` to `outcome` in the code. Otherwise no other changes should be made.

Comment: So I've managed to implement all the code (I think). I'm not used to C, so one part puzzles me: "return (i < out.size()) ? probs[i] : 0.0;" Does this mean return (i < size), and also set probs(i) to 0 if (i < size) is true?

Comment: @user8128940 that is called a *ternary operator*. An expression of the form `a = (b) ? c : d` is equivalent to `if (b) a = c else a = d`.

Comment: I've updated my original question with my attempted implementation of your code. Unless I'm doing something wrong, it takes a very long time to complete when n exceeds 10-15. Maybe for my purposes, a simulation is the only option. I ran the test case and it matches with your 0.83.

Comment: @user8128940 That is to be expected. As I said in the answer this has a time complexity of `O(m^(n-1) * log m)`, i.e. it rises exponentially with the number of bets. This is the price paid for  a *guaranteed* exact solution, which Monte Carlo does not give.